# Sockets not working in AWS ec2 using PHP?

Tags: php, sockets, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, websocket

Unable to make socket.io working on AWS EC2

```
 https://mydoamin.com:2120/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NQpMyRI net::ERR_TIMED_OUT
i.create @ socket.io.js?v=1609310849:7
```

Localhost everything working fine the way it should be working but on live environment, I am getting above error.

When I connect using `[workerman][1]` and starting it using CLI on was ubuntu instance it is working fine

Somehow ports are not working properly even I have added it in security groups under inbound settings:-

And now this error after configuring:

```
<?php
use kriss\webMsgSender\WebMsgSender;

return [
   'components' => [
       // others
       WebMsgSender::COMPONENT_NAME => [
           'class' => WebMsgSender::class,
           'pushApiClientHost' => '0.0.0.0',
           'logCategory' => 'webMsgSender',
       ],
   ],
];
```

**New error**

```
socket.io.js?v=1609310849:7 GET https://myDoamin.com:2120/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NQpU3PA net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

[Extension](https://github.com/krissss/yii2-web-msg-sender) I am using

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you configure socket io to listen to be bonded to all IP addresses, not just the localhost

so instead of

```
<?php
use kriss\webMsgSender\WebMsgSender;

return [
    'components' => [
        // others
        WebMsgSender::COMPONENT_NAME => [
            'class' => WebMsgSender::class,
            'pushApiClientHost' => 'localhost',
            'logCategory' => 'webMsgSender',
        ],
    ],
];
```

change to

```
<?php
use kriss\webMsgSender\WebMsgSender;

return [
    'components' => [
        // others
        WebMsgSender::COMPONENT_NAME => [
            'class' => WebMsgSender::class,
            'pushApiClientHost' => '0.0.0.0',
            'logCategory' => 'webMsgSender',
        ],
    ],
];
```

basically change localhost to 0.0.0.0

Comment: After changes, this is coming socket.io.js?v=1609310849:7 GET https://myDoamin.com:2120/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NQpU3PA net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Comment: try the telnet first to confirm the connectivity     telnet  myDoamin.com 2120